# VBA Value not recognized

Tags: vba, excel-formula, formula

Running a VBA code to run automated emails based on date. If the date equals today then the value becomes "100" which should trigger the email macro.

I only have this set up to run based off cell value which is the reason for the IF cell = today then "100".

The issue I believe is that the VBA code is looking at the formula and not the value so it is not being triggered. This only works if I manually input the number 100 and not when the formula runs its calculation.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Value < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("I36:I44"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 100 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your context seems to be dependent on a formula recalculating, in which case you need to write your code in the [Worksheet_Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event procedure

Comment: I'm not similar with this type of procedure. What in the code would have to be re wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event procedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I36:I44"), 100) Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
```

as this runs whenever the calculated result of a formula on the sheet changes.

Comment: Thanks @Spectral Instance. This however is sending the email anytime I change a cell. Is there a way to trigger the email only when the formula = 100 and not have this run every time a cell is edited?

Comment: You could add another line to clear the `I36:I44` range immediately after the `Call` line so that the condition for sending the email is only satisfied once - your use-case isn't entirely clear...

Comment: That's my fault for the lack of info. Cells F36:H44 are all dates. If any of those dates = today() then column I generates the value 100. When column I shows 100 then I'm looking for an email to be sent. Only reason for column I is I was not sure how to accomplish this without that extra helper column.

Comment: The code might be better off in the Workbook_Open() event (so that it will only be run once), since the value of `Today()` is only going to change once every 24 hours - you'd need to advise the actual sheet name, though, for me to update the code. If this doesn't suit then you need to advise how the `I36:I44` _can_ be changed so that the existing procedure only runs once.

Comment: Would it be more applicable to run something along the lines of if the range G36:H44 is today's date, send the email? Only reason for I36:I44 was the code prior to this was only able to send based off values and even that wasn't working correctly. Dates are shown as the short date.

Comment: Only if, afterwards, that range can be cleared - otherwise the code will continue to run...

Comment: I think that would be more applicable to run if G36:I44 is today's date then send email. Are you able to help with that?

Comment: If today's date is in G36:I44 then it will still be in those cells after the code has run...
How about designating a specific cell to indicate whether the code has already run, or not - if that's FALSE then the code runs, and sets that cell to TRUE, so that it will only run once ?

Comment: Understood. Sounds like the 100 value may be best. if I36:I44 equals 100 then send email. clear contents afterwords

Comment: So add `Range("I36:I44").ClearContents` immediately before the `End If`

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the chat and help on getting this working!